# What do you do with a question that appears to be interpreted not in a way you intended?

Tags: discussion, moderation, vote-to-close

Today I asked a question after being frustrated on a time consuming effort in finding an appropriate trip. I was frustrated since the usual corporate travel agent wasn't helping and the my usual options I use to plan leisure trips took me quite some time to combine with my working schedule. 
So I asked: [Can a group of people become a travel agent](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21898/can-a-group-of-people-become-a-travel-agent). After reviewing the answers, it appears that the question was not worded well. In the sense thought that I wanted to start might own business. I am merely interested in getting a personal gateway to business travel, so to speak. 
I can't delete, since it got attention and response. At the same time it is not what I was asking. 
Should I;

1. Flag the moderator for deletion?
2. Vote to close as off topic?
3. Ignore and just write a new question?

Comment: Edit the current question to better fit what everyone assumed it was when answering, then open a new one with clearer/more precise wording for what you'd really meant?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend doing an edit to the question and clarifying your intent. The people who posted their answers can edit accordingly or delete their answers as they see fit. The latter is not an uncommon occurrence - many people DO delete their answers when they see it doesn't fit.

Comment: They delete their answers and afterwards they will get punished for that ...

Comment: @user3470 unless you have an unhealthy obsession with your rep there's no punishment involved; and there are several badges related to deleting your own content.  In particular, two people on that question could get a disciplined badge which is one of the harder ones to earn.

Comment: First of all, deleting content on this site is VERY risky. I know what I am talking about. If you think that your own question is misunderstood, ask a new one and try to formulate it properly.